# Appending to elements within an Rcpp List

Tags: r, rcpp

Possibly a stupid question, but I've hunted around a lot for an answer and been unable to find one:

I'm trying to write a file reader, a la `fread` or `read.delim` but implemented in C++ and connected to R via Rcpp. The easiest way to do this and have it output a data.frame is have it produce a `List` of vectors - one for each column - and set the class to `data.frame`

```
List foo;
foo.push_back(column);
foo.attr("class") = "data.frame";
return foo;
```

Simple enough, and I've done it before. Unfortunately:

1. The file(s) I want to read in can have a varying number of fields;
2. This model only works elegantly if you're reading from the file column-wise, while actual files tend to be read row-wise.

So, the answer is to be able to define foo and then, for each row I read in, push_back() a field on to each of foo's underlying vectors:

```
List foo(1);
foo[0].push_back("turnip");
```

Unfortunately I can't work out how to do that: it doesn't appear that a List's member vectors can be pushed_back() to, since this results in the error "Rcpp::Vector<19>::Proxy has no member named push_back()"

So, my question: is there any way to append to a vector within an Rcpp list? Or is my only option to read the file in column-by-column, appending the resulting vectors to "foo", and bite the performance cost that's going to result from having to iterate through it [number of columns] times instead of once?

Hopefully this question is clear enough. Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a semi-hard problem when you know neither rows nor columns beforehand.

In a for-work, remained-closed project a few years ago, I collected my data as a variant type (using the corresponding Boost class) and converted at the end.

In [Rblpapi](https://github.com/armstrtw/Rblpapi/) (to which I contributed some other code), Whit tried a few approaches and ended up defining [his own helper functions](https://github.com/armstrtw/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/blpapi_utils.cpp#L254) and I have been meaning to distill / refactor this and discuss it with Kevin -- but that hasn't happened yet.

So feel free to come up with something better :)

Generally speaking, and getting back to your problem, we frequently receive data *row-wise*,  often via call-backs.  The Rcpp types (wrapping R types) do *very poorly* when you append element by element -- so don't do the naive `push_back` as you will end up copying *a lot*.

So if you know your types, do `std::list` over corresponding `std::vector<T>` for the given `T`. These vectors you can grow.  Once you have them, assembling a `Rcpp::List` and hence `Rcpp::DataFrame` is easier.

Comment: That makes sense. So to summarise; even if it appears on-its-face inefficient, the most efficient approach is probably iterating repeatedly through the file extracting each column in turn as a std::vector, and then adding that vector to the list in its entirety?

Comment: In many cases, you can make do reading row-wise, growing your data structures and converting at the end.  Doing it fully _generally_ and _efficient_ is hard.